# How can I prevent a part of my html page from being cached in the browser?

Tags: javascript, dom, browser-cache

I have been troubled with all the browsers not being able to re-parse some markup language that is being generated via java-script.So the idea is to test getting the reference to the cache of the element(div in my case) which encloses the markup and clear it programmatically via  javascript.Is it possible someway?

Comment: Send the appropriate `Cache-Control` header

Comment: I am afraid that might prevent the whole page to be cached

Answer (score 0):

There is a very elegant way to do this. Ajax comes in handy when caching a webpage. Simply cache the whole page and send an AJAX request for the parts you don't want to be cached.